# Запускаю тесты, программа просит сослаться на настройки и окружение, а что конкретно, понять не могу. Текст ошибки приложен ниже

Tags: python, django, юнит-тесты

test setup failed
cls = <class 'store.tests.test_logic.LogicTestCase'>

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
```

> ```
>   super().setUpClass()
> ```

...(тут были ссылки на основной код Django)

self = <LazySettings [Unevaluated]>, name = 'DATABASES'

```
def _setup(self, name=None):
    """
    Load the settings module pointed to by the environment variable. This
    is used the first time settings are needed, if the user hasn't
    configured settings manually.
    """
    settings_module = os.environ.get(ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
    if not settings_module:
        desc = ("setting %s" % name) if name else "settings"
```

> ```
>       raise ImproperlyConfigured(
> ```

```
            "Requested %s, but settings are not configured. "
            "You must either define the environment variable %s "
            "or call settings.configure() before accessing settings."
            % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
        )
```

E           django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: А что это - "self = <LazySettings [Unevaluated]>"?

Comment: Джанго приложению для работы нужна конфигурация, которая задается в каком-то модуле и путь к модулю нужно указать в переменной окружения `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. Либо запускайте тесты с помощью `manage.py` (который устанавливает эту переменную), как написано тут https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests либо сами вручную задайте эту переменную окружения. Как именно зависит от того, как запускаете тесты